# php loop: repeat just once

Tags: php

How can I get a php loop to print out:

1 1 2 2 3 3 all the way to 250 250. So basically count from 1 - 250 but print out each number twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 250; $i++){
   echo "$i ";
   echo "$i ";
}
```

Comment: Note you'll have a trailing space after the last 250 with this function.

Comment: ok my question was even dumber than the one that asked how to convert a number to its negative counterpart ...

Comment: The `echo`s can be combined so you could have a oneliner:
`for ($i = 1; $i <= 250; $i++) echo "$i $i ";`

Comment: Code golf time?  `foreach (range(1,250) as $i) echo "$i $i ";` shaves 1 char!

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 250; $i++)
{
    echo $i, ' ', $i, ($i != 250 ? ' ' : NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
implode(' ', array_map('floor', range(1, 250.5, 0.5)));
```

Comment: This would be fun but implicit way to do it. I'd recommend one of the more obvious solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 250; $i++) {
    echo $i; // print the first time
    echo $i; // print the second time
}
```

You can obviously print duplicated value with one echo statement and make the code one line shorter.

Comment: Note this function won't print spaces between the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The approach to solve this is loop. You can use loops of 4 types in PHP **while, for, do...while, foreach**. Except ***for...each*** you can do it in  other three ways. For each is used for arrays. I am writing all three loops.

***while loop***

```
$i = 1; // initialize a variable which can be used else where in the program
while($i<=250)
{
    echo $i."  ".$i;
 $i++;
}
```

***for loop***

```
for($i = 1; $i <=250; $i++)
{
echo $i." ".$i;
}
```

the variable initialized in the braces of for loop can just be used with in the loop.
**do while loop**

```
$i = 1;
do{
   echo $i." ".$i;
 }while($i<=250);
```